# JavaScript notifications not working as expected in function

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, youtube-iframe-api

I recently made a YouTube JukeBox. I have everything I want done, except I am trying to get Notifications to work/show on the play event only if the previous video has ended.

I have tried setting a variable then updating it when the video when a video ends to true, however it keeps returning "undefined" when I check it in the play event.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event)
{
   var videoData = player.getVideoData();
   if (event.data == 0)
   {
       var videend = 1;
       player.loadVideoById($("input[name=video]:radio:checked").closest('tr').next().find('input').prop("checked", true).val());
       $('.playlist').scrollTo($("input[name=video]:radio:checked").closest('tr'));
   }
   if (event.data == 1)
   {
       $("#info").css("display","none");
       if(videend == 1)
       {
           var videend = 0;
           new Notification(videoData['author'], {
               dir: "auto",
               lang: "",
               body: videoData['title'],
               icon: "http://vman315.com/base/images/Pinkie-Pie-mustache.png",
           });
       }
    document.title = '\u25B6 ' + videoData['title'];
   }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/83tju/1/)

If anyone could possibly provide some insight into what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work for me in Google Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m

It appears as though notifications in Chrome are restricted from running automatically and you have to go into your web browser and have them set to either, allow notifications from all websites without asking, or ask each time for a notification.

My browser was set to ask each time for allowing a notification. You do not however have any code in your document to ask for permission to run a notification. When i set my browser to run notifications without asking then it worked properly.

The only other issue being your

```
"var videend = 1;"
```

was not being accessed inside of the local function. I moved that inside of the function and then your if statement for notifications started working.

http://jsfiddle.net/83tju/3/

Helpful resources

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/#permission

After reading those resources it appears as though the syntax you are using to create notifications does not work on the version of chrome i am using, this might explain why i had to stop my browser from asking for notifications? Not sure. I will have to look at this later on an updated browser.

Comment: Yes however that means the variable is being set back to 1 every time `onPlayerStateChange` is called, which is every time the player pauses/plays/buffers/ends. The goal is to only show on new video play. I wrote all of this using Aurora & IE8 for testing.

Comment: Global Variables in JavaScript -- http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable


I updated the jsfiddle to have a global variable now so that the notification only plays on the first play of the song. http://jsfiddle.net/83tju/4/

Comment: I had tried `window.videend` however it didn't work for me, but this works. I forgot to add `Notification.requestPermission` to the original JSFiddle, that maybe why it didn't ask for premission on your version of Chrome. [End results](http://jsfiddle.net/83tju/8/), I added `videonote.onshow = function(){setTimeout(function(){videonote.close()}, 5000);}` so they would close in Chrome.


Thanks for the help. I would upvote but not enough rep.